# no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

The title is the error I'm getting and I have no idea why, but here is some information so hopefully someone on here can elucidate me.

I have subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as this saves me calculating the frames for the cell's myself (perhaps this is an issue?) in `prepareLayout`. I then use the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` information to calculate a supplementary view that over lays it, I get the layout I desire.

I use `performBatchUpdates:completion:` to add,remove and update the view. Insertion works fine, however deleting items is when the error shown in the title appears.

So I know why the error is happening but i don't know **why it should even be happening**. To clarify with an example going through a scenario that causes the issue

1. Start with 1 item with 1 supplementary view 1 section
2. Add two more items (`prepareLayout` sees 3 items with 3 supplementary views)
3. Delete item (`prepareLayout` sees 2 views with 2 supplementary views)
4. `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:` is called asking for attributes for index path with **section:0 and item:2**
5. Crash because it asked for attributes for a third supplementary view even though earlier it called prepare layout setting up 2 items and 2 supplementary views
6. Throw hands up in resignation and despair

so the offending function as far as i can tell is:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.layoutInfo[elementKind][indexPath];
}
```

which of course is called automagically by the internal networking of `UICollectionView` so I have no clue as to why it's asking for that supplementary view at that index path.

Anyone got any ideas? Perhaps it's how i use `performBatchUpdates:completion:` but deletion worked fine until adding supplementary views. I can provide more code/explanation as necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I scoured the forums looking for an answer and came across a few suggestions. None of them gave me the succour I needed, and eventually in the interest of meeting deadlines, I dropped the use of supplementary views altogether.

A few weeks later out of curiosity I looked around again and eventually [came across the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976431/supplementary-views-not-being-deleted) and now I'm back to using supplementary views again.

So, don't forget to return your:

```
- (NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind
{
    return self.removedIndexPaths;
}
```

to your collection view layout.

Comment: @micromanc3r Those are the words of someone who has endured an issue with no clue why its not working trying random stuff fruitlessly for days on end. Glad I could help end the misery.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a crash you could return dummy attributes for all those indexPaths that are not valid any more. Something like this could help to prevent your crash:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = self.layoutInfo[elementKind][indexPath]; // add some safety checks if this access creates an out of bounds issue

// create dummy layoutAttributes
// the workaround
if (layoutAttributes == nil) {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *dummyLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:elementKind withIndexPath:indexPath];
    dummyLayoutAttributes.frame = CGRectZero;
    dummyLayoutAttributes.hidden = YES;
    layoutAttributes = dummyLayoutAttributes;
}

return layoutAttributes;
```

This still leads to objects in your view stack that should not be there, but they are hidden and don't create a crash. The next time the `UICollectionView` updates it's layout it should clean out the old hidden views.

Comment: from where you get self.layoutInfo?